# Xamarin Forms AppCenter SDK Namespace Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to add the AppCenter SDK functionality to my Xamarin Forms app (iOS and Android) and am following the documentation from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin).

I am experiencing an issue with the namespaces not seeming to line up quite right. Here is a screenshot with some comments:

[image]

As you can see, `AppCenter.Start(...)` does not appear to exist but `Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start(...)` does.

The shared project for my Xamarin Forms app is a .NET Standard 2.0 shared lib.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Additional setup screenshots:

[image: NuGet Setup]
[image: Shared Project Setup]

Comment: did you follow the instructions in section 4.1?

Comment: Yes, I’m not missing the using statements

Comment: Can it be that your own app namespace is AppCenter?

Comment: @EvZ, no... namespace for the app is EmployeeApp.*

Comment: Hi Ryan,

This is Ben from the App Center team. Can you get in touch through our support? There's a big blue button in the bottom right corner of the App Center Portal.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the screenshot attached, AppCenter is a class under Microsoft.AppCenter namespace, so what you are writing is correct only `Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start(...)`

You can find the same by pressing F12 on AppCenter in `AppCenter.Start(...)`
[image]

Comment: As stated above, I have the using statements added correctly, so this is not a good answer.

Comment: Your statement is written in comments, please update that in question as well.